# Need to find the source code for print or printf in python

Tags: python, printing, printf

I am working on something that I cannot entirely talk about. All I can say is that I am a student in Information Security and Computer Science.

I simply need to change some source code of something deep inside python. For now, I would specifically like to change source code inside the builtin print function. Unfortunately, I can't find it defined any where in the python source code files.

Any ideas whatsoever?

Thanks very much.

EDIT: Specifically the question intended to ask if the print function in Python could be overwritten with something else. This was intended as to plant a backdoor in the Python interpreter.

Comment: It's impossible to provide a meaningful answer without more information about what you are trying to achieve. If you are wanting to change what `print` does, for example, you may just be wanting to replace `sys.stdout`.

Comment: I found this question while looking for more info of how print treats unicode strings. The answers were useful to me. Thank you! 
Also I think that the title can be changed to: "Need to change ..." instead of "Need to find...".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In cpython, the `print` function is implemented in C, not Python. You can find the [source code here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/937fa81500e2/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1567), but you'll have to recompile cpython in order for changes to take effect.

For an implementation of `print` in Python, have a look at [pypy's version](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/ed43c2dc0a42843bbf9637b14a2c30dfe2785295/pypy/module/__builtin__/app_io.py?at=default#cl-78).

Comment: Thanks phihag. That's exactly the plan. I want to recompile this for it to make it work.

Two questions —

1. Can I do the same thing for Python instead of cpython?
2. Will someone be able read the source for it using inspect module or any other way?

Comment: "cpython" is the reference implementation for Python. When you type `python`, it is cpython you are running. Other implementations are different (jython, for example, for Python in Java).

Comment: Oh! Just read about it. Thanks very much. [Wow me!]

Comment: It sounds like you don't know exactly what you are needing to do to achieve your goal. Please, expand on what your problem is and what you are trying to achieve. Recompiling Python is almost certainly not what you need to do or the best way of achieving it.

Comment: 'It sounds like you don't know exactly what you are needing to do to achieve your goal. Please, expand on what your problem is and what you are trying to achieve.'

Sorry for my ignorance, but unfortunately I cannot. Please pardon me.

I think I know what I am doing. I selectively need to change the source code to accomplish something in python.

'Recompiling Python is almost certainly not what you need to do'

Umm. Again I am sorry as I cannot stress this further. Thanks! :)

Comment: @omniDETH As Burhan pointed out, in general, each Python implementation will implement `print` differently, but you're of course free to assign any other function to the name `print` and/or `__builtins__.print`. I don't see why you should care about someone reading the source code (which it's a good idea to publish, and a [bad idea to keep private, for security reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle)), but if you write something in C and compile it, users will only see your code's effect, and no comments or so.

Comment: Thanks Phihag. I am aware of Kerckhoffs's principle. Security by obscurity is the worst of way of doing things. I just need to keep things the way I've described. Sorry I cannot disclose much. Probably later. Apologies again. :)

Comment: @omniDETH I think what everyone's pointing out is that you're adamant you need to re-compile Python and that's the correct way to do whatever it is you're doing, but at the same time you needed to come onto SO (very cloak and dagger style) because you weren't able to track down some relevant code from a public repository... I hope it works out, but I guess we'll never know ;)

Comment: Remember that `print` is not a function in Python 2 unless you have imported `print_function` from `__future__`. Only in that situation and for Python 3 can you override `__builtins__.print`. But if you're doing that, you see that someone else can override it. Just like `sys.stdout`.

Comment: @Chris — Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the reply. This really helped!

Comment: cpython is now on github, [built-in print](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bdf4298ae2c1d720fd808520267ca3a4e56df842/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1768)