# Python — arguments to builtin_print method in bltinmodule.c

Tags: python

This question follows from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098524/need-to-find-the-source-code-for-print-or-printf-in-python).

I don't have to change the entire implementation of builtin_print(). I simply need to look for a particular argument for e.g. --- 'python'.

For the following statement —

```
from __future__ import print_function
print('python')
```

whenever there's a print for 'python', I want my code to do something else. The issue is:

```
builtin_print(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
```

args is a PyObject type. I've no way to strcmp or memcmp args[1] with 'Python'.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you need to override sys.stdout.write() or `print()` to any file? Can you just monkey-patch __builtin__.print?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apparently, I am unaware of Monkey Patching. Given I've only a day left to complete this work and I am at very last step, I will be reading on Monkey Patching in the coming days.

Comment: [it is simpler than it sounds](http://ideone.com/SSfUbx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects the Python interpreter deals with are Python objects, not C ones. Therefore, you'll have to use interpreter-specific functions to compare against a C string, like this:

```
PyObject *o = PyTuple_GetItem(args, i);
if (PyUnicode_CheckExact(o) && PyUnicode_CompareWithASCIIString(o, "Python")==0){
    printf("Do something else ..\n");
} else {
    err = PyFile_WriteObject(o, file, Py_PRINT_RAW);
    if (err)
        return NULL;
}
```

Add it in place of the [current code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/937fa81500e2/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1671). For the older 2.7.3 release, you have to use the PyString* family of functions, like

```
if (PyUnicode_CheckExact(o)) {
    PyObject* utf8 = PyUnicode_AsUTF16String(o);
    if (strcmp(PyString_AsString(o), "Python")==0) {
        printf("Do something else (unicode)\n");
    }
    Py_DECREF(utf8);
} else if (PyString_CheckExact(o) && strcmp(PyString_AsString(o), "Python")==0){
    printf("Do something else (str) ..\n");
} else {
    err = PyFile_WriteObject(o, file, Py_PRINT_RAW);
    if (err)
        return NULL;
}
```

Note that this does not handle unicode strings (`u'Python'`), for which you . You may also be interested in modifying `case PRINT_ITEM` in `Modules/ceval.c`, which handles the print *statement*.

Note that there are other ways for a Python program to print than to call `print`, including writing to `sys.stdout` or letting a navtive (C) function do the printing.

Comment: Okay great, I will give this one a shot! Thanks a ton.

Comment: I applied the code and I see a warning

warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyUnicode_CompareWithASCIIString'.

Do I need to include some header file for this?

Regards

Comment: @omniDETH In the newest hg checkout (`a1cd431a71c6`), this should work fine verbatim. If you're working with an older version of the source code, you'll have to adapt it (and if your version is really old (2.x), you'll want to check for `str` as well, as this only matches `print(u'Python')` in 2.x). `PyUnicode_CompareWithASCIIString` is in `Include/unicodeobject.h`.

Comment: Thanks phihag. I must I am new to python and have undertaken a big project — so I've learned a lot. I am just noob when it's down to embedded python. I am using 2.7.2/3 and the specification requires me to implement it. Can you please write in code how to do that? I honestly have no idea. Sincerely apologize for the same.

Comment: Even after importing unicodeobject.h, it says —

'undefined reference to PyUnocode_CompareWithASCIIString'

Comment: @omniDETH This code should work verbatim for 3.3 as well. Note that as others have repeatedly pointed out, your overarching problem has most likely a much simpler solution than running code in a modified Python interpreter, so you should really ask for a solution for *that*. Don't fall into the trap of [dividing a problem into two parts, one easy and one impossible](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/11/04/10233798.aspx).

Comment: @omniDETH Oh, than your approach is indeed the right one. On what Python version (i.e. checked out from where, and which branch?) do you get the error message?

Comment: I am using 2.7.3 on debian.

@phihag, Now that you know, I will be editing my comment. This is a project based assignment, I don't want this to leak. Hopefully, you can understand.

Comment: I am unsure, I simply downloaded the most stable release of 2.7.3 and I am trying to work on that.

Comment: I am downloading 3.3 and trying to accomplish the same on that.

Comment: Updated the answer with instructions for 2.7.3. It's way harder there, since many programmers use byte strings in 2.x, even when they shouldn't.

Comment: Phihag, when you say — 'Add it in place of the current code.', do you mean I replace everything after line 1671 in bltinmodule.c in function — builtin_print()?

Comment: No, just lines 1671 - 1674, where the individual items are printed.